# Changes not reflected in PhpStorm after GIT checkout on remote machine

Tags: git, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm to work on remote project in VM. Everything is good except when I checkout branch on VM I don't see changes reflected in PhpStorm.

I can download the whole project again but it takes to long.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you done a `git pull`?

Comment: Found answer in different resource. I had to right click on folder in project tree, deployment > Sync with Deployment and then accept all changes.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to PhpStorm, and looking for a solution for this using the latest version of PhpStorm, if anybody knows, how to update the live site after I've checked out to the branch, (without opening each and every file one by one that has a change in it), please please help me. Thank you. (Works perfectly in VSCode though... just saying.) I'd offer a bounty but I haven't got that much LOL.

Answer (score 5):

as is told in the phpstorm documentation:
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Sync+changes+and+automatic+upload+to+a+deployment+server+in+PhpStorm

> By default, only files changed by the IDE will be uploaded. If files
>   are changed by some other process such as a VCS branch change,
>   transpilation of Sass or LESS or a File Watcher, they are not
>   automatically uploaded. To change this behavior and autoupload these
>   changes as well, enable the Upload external changes option.

Comment: Yeah, for me it only catches these if PHPStorm regains focus and it is delayed a bit in any case.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case (PHPStorm 2016.1). I have to use an external tool (SmartGit) to update my project. In that case PHPStorm picks up the changes and upload the modified files to the deploy server, but it doesn't work with the internal version control management tools.